# Prevent listing of automatically mounted flash drives in Kodi

Tags: kodi

Kodi (16.1, built Dec. 4th, 2016) running on Arch Linux (4.4.37-1-ARCH) on a Pi 2 B keeps listing all attached flash drives automatically. How to prevent automatic listing of (selected) mounted flash drives?

There are two USB flash drives attached to the system and mounted via `fstab` using their UUID. They have specific mount points that fit their use. In fact one of those flash drives got nothing to do with any media files of use for Kodi. In Kodi's main menus "Picture", "Video / Files", and "Music / Files" I manually created links to the relevant directories (e.g. to `/media/music` using "Add Music Source" in "Music / Files" of the on-screen menu). In those menus however Kodi choses to automatically include the two flash drives - which is of little use to me and clutters the interface.

In the on-screen menu I haven't been able to find a relevant setting to change this behaviour, albeit selecting all "advanced" settings. Fiddling with the [`advancedsettings.xml`](http://kodi.wiki/view/Advancedsettings.xml) especially with the `<excludefromlisting>` settings did not change a thing either.

I suspect `UDisks` to be the culprit here as kodi.log shows after enabling debug logs:

```
INFO: UDisks: Added /bla/bla
```

So I tried to [hide selected partitions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks) creating a udev rule (`/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`)

```
ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="XXXX-XXXX", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

Again, to no avail. Kodi just does not care. As per @goldilocks comment that udev rule makes little sense since it mixes udisks and udisks2 notations. Trying a rule for udisks however (setting aside the issue of changing block device names for the moment) did not change a thing either.

```
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

So again, how to prevent those drives to show up?

Comment: I notice you've actually mixed and matched some things from that Arch wiki page -- namely, you're using `ID_FS_UUID` as a trigger to set `UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE`, although the former is paired with `UDISKS_IGNORE`.  This may be because udev has a lot of gotchas with using the `ENV` stuff, or it may simply be because (as stated there) "if you are using udisks2, the above will not work as `UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE` is no longer supported. Instead, use `UDISKS_IGNORE`...".

Comment: Kodi's page reads that UDISKS_IGNORE is for udisks2 and thus not working, I guess I will look into it again

Comment: You've found some cracks to fall between, in other words.

Comment: @goldilocks I was really hoping that there is a way to handle the situation in Kodi itself (... and of course to get a hat along the way).

Comment: Nearly three years on, it seems there's still no solution to this :( I want a mounted drive, I just don't want kodi to show it.